# system of pdes equations

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to solve those group analytically in Mathematica?

```
eqns = {D[y[x, t], t] - ϵ (G[x, t] - y[x, t]) == 0, 
D[G[x, t], t] - 1/A D[G[x, t], x, x] - B (y[x, t] - G[x, t]) == 0};
```

I am looking for both `y[x, t], G[x,t]`

Comment: V 12 can't solve them. You did not show what you tried.    `ClearAll[y, x, t, G, epsilon, A, B];
    pdes = {D[y[x, t], t] - epsilon (G[x, t] - y[x, t]) == 0, 
      D[G[x, t], t] - 1/A D[G[x, t], x, x] - B (y[x, t] - G[x, t]) == 0};
    DSolve[eqns, {y[x, t], G[x, t]}, {x, t}]` See help for examples how to use `DSolve` to solve pde's

Comment: Dear Nasser, i solved them by my hand using L.T but i wanted to got the ans from mathematica but i coudnt

Comment: `Maple` can solve,and is more powerfull than `Mathematica` for solving `PDE's`.See: https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2019_and_mma_12/index.htm